# Long/short button press doesn`t work with IF statements - Need some help

Tags: python, gpiozero

I am trying to build a simple game and I have the following problem.
My code is executed but the button presses cannot be detected whatever I am trying.
There are no errors and I cannot figure out why it is not working
My goal is to execute specific statement IF button A is pressed or long pressed, and the same for button B.

If I wrote a simple test to print the PIN number of the pressed button on the console everything works and I don`t have any issues and my problem is not from the hardware.

This is a sample from the code with the IF statements logic.

```
from gpiozero import Button

buttonA = Button(16)
buttonB = Button(26)
leftScore = 0
rightScore = 0

while leftScore <= 40 and rightScore <= 40:  # maximum points
        if buttonA.when_held(hold_time=3):  
            leftScore += 2
            print(leftScore)
        elif buttonA.when_activated():
            leftScore +=1
            print(leftScore)
         elif buttonB.when_held(hold_time=3):  
            rightScore += 2
            print(rightScore)            
        elif buttonB.when_activated():
            rightScore +=1
            print(rightScore)
```

Comment: The documentation (https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-use-button-when-pressed-and-button-when-held-together) follows a callback pattern (when this button is pressed, call this function). I suggest trying that, although you will need to do something  to stop your script simply exiting as soon as it's configured everything.

Comment: the way that your code is written, buttonA excludes buttonB

Comment: i do not know if the code you presented actually works ... i am commenting on the logic of the code you presented .... all four of the decision blocks should be `if` statements so that one `if` does not exclude another `if` from executing ... the print statements should be at the end, outside of the `if` blocks so that the group of the `if` statements executes as quickly as possible, because the program is time sensitive

Comment: This is a combination of simple python programming errors and failure to read the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does error:

```
----> 1 buttonA.when_held(hold_time=3)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

You're mixing up the programming paradigms provided by gpiozero.

- `button.is_pressed` - immediately returns `True` or `False`
- `button.when_pressed = foo` - a property you can set to a callback
- `button.when_held = bar` - a property you can set to a callback

(and `pressed` is an alias for `activated` so you don't need to use `activated`)

Example of `is_pressed`:

```py
while True:
    if button.is_pressed:
        print("pressed")
```

Example of `when_pressed`:

```py
def pressed():
    print("pressed")

button.when_pressed = pressed
```

(no loop is required)

Example of `when_held`:

```py
button = Button(hold_time=5)

def held():
    print("held")

button.when_held = held
```

(no loop is required)

You can use `when_pressed` and `when_held` at the same time (as per [this FAQ](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-use-button-when-pressed-and-button-when-held-together)).

Do you want to give each player 1 point for pressing, and 3 for holding? As long as you don't mind them overlapping you probably want something like this:

```
from gpiozero import Button

button_a = Button(16)
button_b = Button(26)

btn_scores = {
    button_a: 0,
    button_b: 0,
}

def pressed(btn):
    btn_scores[btn] += 1

def held(btn):
    btn_scores[btn] += 3

for btn in btn_scores.keys():
   btn.when_pressed = pressed
   btn.when_held = held
```

The only problem is this adds 4 points for a hold because it adds 1 for the press then 3 for the hold (see the FAQ linked above).

Comment: Yes you are right @ben_nuttall.

Comment: I manage to fix my code using only the first option `button.is_pressed `. I will add some more buttons to skip the problem with long press. Thanks for your reply